# node.h cannot be opened

Tags: c++, node.js

I am running into issues with the [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) c++ libs, so at first I tried to include `node.h` and it failed. I tried to search for the header file but I could not find it, then I got `nan`. I was hoping that I could just skip the issue but since `nan` includes `node.h` there is no way around the issue and I can not find a guide on how to get the header file.

Comment: Copy the exact error messages into the question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63544525/edit) it.

Comment: Did you install the source for node?  Or just the headers?  node.h is definitely part of https://nodejs.org/download/release/latest-v14.x/node-v14.8.0-headers.tar.gz so if you installed that you should have node.h